# Read Image as base64 string; Out of memory exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to convert images in a directory as base64 strings. when I test it in local computer it works, but on the server it gives out of memory exception:
here is my method:

```
 private ImageDataViewModel ReadImagesFromDisk(Guid id)
    {
        List<string> imageList = new List<string>();
        ImageDataViewModel imageDataViewModel = new ImageDataViewModel();
        string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/BusinessImages/" + id.ToString());
        try
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                var images = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .ToList();

                string fileName = id.ToString();

                foreach (var item in images)
                {

                    using (Image image = Image.FromFile(item))
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
                            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);                                                        
                            imageList.Add(base64String);                                                     
                        }
                    }
                }
                imageDataViewModel.Id = id;
                imageDataViewModel.ImageData = imageList;

                return imageDataViewModel;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }            
    }
```

I don't know how this happens. Is there any way to handle this problem?

Comment: OOM can be due to many reasons.May be there are too many heavy images on the server  May be there is any other parallel task happening during this operation which is consuming memory. Do you get the stack trace on which line is it crashing?>

Comment: You put all yours images in base64 in imageList in memory and maybe you did it for each request so in a server with a real activity you explose the memory capacity of the server. Try a singleton to ensure you did only once.

Comment: Why would you want to store a list of images in main memory? And a Base 64 string requires 2.7 times as much space as the original byte array...

Comment: There are two images that I try to convert: the first one is 19kb and the second one is 35kb (It does not seem to be too heavy!!) and also this request is the only request that I'm making.

Comment: Is there another way that I don't need to save images in memory and convert them to base64 string? please elaborate

Comment: These are small images indeed. Most likely your OOM is due to something else. But there is certainly an easy optimization for your code. Instead of reading and decoding the image from disk (Image.FromFile) and then encoding and saving it into a memory stream (Image.Save) and finally retrieving the memory as a byte array, you can do it directly using File.ReadAllBytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(yourfilepath + fname);
string fileName = yourfilename.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
```

try this,
This will return whole file.